# Can Zebra ZETI read barcode?

Tags: barcode, rfid

I'm trying the ZETI interface on a RFD8500 reader. I connect through a terminal, and most commands work as intended. However, the `readbarcode` command (which is just mentioned in the docs, without any description), when issued, immediately returns empty result, eg `Status: OK, BarcodeType: , Barcode:`. How is the command supposed to be used?? Can ZETI read barcodes at all?

Comment: Hello, I have to do exactly the same. Did you manage to resolve your issue by using ZETI for barcode reading ?

Comment: @Armand: it's been a long time. if I remember correctly, I ended up using two different libraries, one for RFID, and a different one for reading barcode. Both using the java libraries provided, didn't manage to make the low level interface work at all

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the device with both barcode and rfid reader? 
I'd suggest to try first switching from RFID mode to barcode mode by issuing a ZETI command, then if the command still doesn't work I guess it's not supported.

Comment: yes, it is that device, and it is in barcode barcode reading mode. But reading with ZETI does nothing

Comment: Afaik the supported way to communicate with the barcode scanner is via the scanner SDK, probably this ZETI command it an artefact or means something else, there are no other commands for the barcode reader in their guide.